# Unity - Instantiate 2 copies at same time?? (Asteroids clone) C#

Tags: unity, c#, instancing

I haven't been at my computer learning code or game dev in a few months and am just starting again. I am trying to make a game very similar to Asteroids. In 3d but fixed camera from above so basically disregarding the Y Axis at the moment.

I have everything working fine so far such as the rocket stays in middle and can rotate, and fire weapon. The Asteroids for now all come from the top side of the screen, and have some code to randomise the X location and speeds.

When the laser hits the Asteroid I want it to destroy that Asteroid and create two more that are half the size and with a Rotation added of 45/-45 degrees.

I have the code that I thought would work but it is only creating one more and not two. (note: as you'll see I have tried making tempAsteroid2 and even asteroidPrefab2, before this I just had the one which I tried to instantiate twice).

What am I missing? why does this code not make two more appear upon laser collision??

Any help massively appreciated as always. Many thanks:

```
public class Asteroid : MonoBehaviour {
float speed;
public GameObject asteroidPrefab, asteroidPrefab2;
public int sizeKey = 2;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    if (sizeKey < 1)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    transform.position.Set(transform.position.x, 0f, transform.position.y);
    speed = Random.Range(0.5f, 2f);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Laser")
    {
        BreakAsteroidInHalf();
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}

void BreakAsteroidInHalf()
{
    GameObject tempAsteroid = asteroidPrefab;
    tempAsteroid.transform.position = transform.position;
    tempAsteroid.transform.Rotate(0, -45, 0);
    tempAsteroid.transform.localScale *= 0.5f;
    tempAsteroid.GetComponent<Asteroid>().sizeKey -= 1;
    Instantiate(tempAsteroid);
    GameObject tempAsteroid2 = asteroidPrefab2;
    tempAsteroid2.transform.position = transform.position;
    tempAsteroid2.transform.Rotate(0, 45, 0);
    tempAsteroid2.transform.localScale *= 0.5f;
    tempAsteroid2.GetComponent<Asteroid>().sizeKey -= 1;
    Instantiate(tempAsteroid2);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Asteroid destroyed and replaced by 2 more");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember that **C#** is an **Object Oriented Programming language**. As such, this is a bad example of how to use it.

Instead of the current solution, try using:

```
void BreakAsteroidsInHalf() {
float rot = 45;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
GameObject asteroid = Instantiate(asteroid, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
asteroid.transform.localScale(0.5,0.5,1);
asteroid.transform.Rotate(0, rot,0);
asteroid.GetComponent<Asteroid>().sizeKey -= 1;
rot -= 90; // If you increase you "i" limit, this will allow you asteroids 
rotate at different degrees.
     }  
Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

This keeps your code succinct, readable, and most importantly, object oriented.

Comment: I like this solution. It is definitely more of a clean way of doing this. I never would have thought to loop the code for creating new objects, instead of simply writing it twice!

Comment: thank you. I am going back to it now. I realise you wrote this 12 hours ago, but if you read this again, could you explain why this is "Object Orientated" and the other one is not? I thought that just by using  a GameObject then by definition it must be OO programming.... I'm am wrong a lot though haha

Comment: i think if I'd understand what you meant by that , It may really help me understand exactly what OO means. I mean i've read about it in several books, tutorials etc, but I kinda just thought all modern day higher level game coding languages (like Java LWJGL, LibGDX, c#, etc) were all OO languages

Comment: @SuperMegaBroBro Absolutely. So essentially OOP requires that you use and reuse classes and objects as much as possible. That means reasonable functions, parameters, constructors, destructors etc to allow for a single "parent" object to be used in many different ways. So while what you were doing isn't "wrong" what you've effectively done is try to make the same object twice by writing identical conditions. Why try to replicate the same object, when you could literally create fewer lines of code that allow an exact clone to be made, but be created in a different environment or have a ...

Comment: ... different purpose. Think of it like creating two humans. The two humans have entirely different goals and things they prioritise, they have different people they care for etc, but regardless, they are humans. Meaning they have eyes, ears, hearts, lungs etc. So instead of many lines of code, writing what a human is, and then rewriting that code to define human 2 and making them roughly similar, we just write a human class and control the parameters we send at the creation of the object (human)

Comment: E.g. createHuman(goals, priority){ //blah } The for loop is equally just a nice touch as in keeping with these rules, it allows you to change one number and the code will still run perfectly well, but the overall outcome will be slightly different. (Three asteroids instead of two etc)

Comment: Does that make a bit of sense?

Comment: yes it does thanks @cmprogram I kinda knew that already but of course I dont fully understand it yet (even though Ive been at it for a long time trying to learn haha) Its since I started using Unity that I feel I got more consfused, due to the way things are instantiated. But you know my original code at top, the two asteroids weren't exactly indentical, on was rotated 45d and the other was -45d. I thought that the Asteroid was the object and the two instances where copies of the original but then rotated separely. I'm still confused but I am going to tinker with it soon and thanks to these...

Comment: ...answers, I will get it working and hopefully understawnd it a bit clearer after that

Answer (score 2):

```
void BreakAsteroidInHalf()
{
    GameObject tempAsteroid = Instantiate(asteroidPrefab);
    tempAsteroid.transform.position = transform.position;
    tempAsteroid.transform.Rotate(0, -45, 0);
    tempAsteroid.transform.localScale *= 0.5f;
    tempAsteroid.GetComponent<Asteroid>().sizeKey -= 1;

    GameObject tempAsteroid2 = Instantiate(asteroidPrefab2);
    tempAsteroid2.transform.position = transform.position;
    tempAsteroid2.transform.Rotate(0, 45, 0);
    tempAsteroid2.transform.localScale *= 0.5f;
    tempAsteroid2.GetComponent<Asteroid>().sizeKey -= 1;

    Destroy(this.gameObject);
    Debug.Log("Asteroid destroyed and replaced by 2 more");
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

Actually, you still have 2 copies, but they have identical transforms.

In your code, you are modifying the prefab here:

```
GameObject tempAsteroid = asteroidPrefab;             //tempAsteroid is the prefab right now, not an instance in the scene
tempAsteroid.transform.position = transform.position; //modifying prefab
tempAsteroid.transform.Rotate(0, -45, 0);             //modifying prefab
tempAsteroid.transform.localScale *= 0.5f;            //modifying prefab
tempAsteroid.GetComponent<Asteroid>().sizeKey -= 1;   //modifying prefab
Instantiate(tempAsteroid);                            //creating an instance
```

The problem with this approach is, when you are using a prefab as the original object, `Instantiate` function will wipe the transform values of the top transform in the hierarchy of prefab, right after the creation of a new instance. So all of your previous modifications to prefab will be replaced by some other values on the new instance.

So instead, we first need to instantiate and then modify the instance on the scene.

Comment: I was just about to put up an answer that was practically the same thing.

Comment: thank you so much guys. So I just need to make a container for each of the two possible new objects, and instantiate it prior to setting any parameters such as position, rotation etc. I'll give this a try now. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to make sure i understand.... Would this be ok: private GameObject newAsteroid1, newAsteroid2;  (as declarations) , then instead of using tempAsteroid just use them directly like that??

Comment: @SuperMegaBroBro I can't say I understand that. May you elaborate?

Comment: hi mate, what I was trying to say was . was the problem that I was Instantiating the same copy of asteroidPrefab? and if so, would a solution be to create two variables called newAsteroid1 and newAsteroid2 and then Instantiate them both at the StartI() and then I can just re-set them to the position etc upon Laser collision? - its hard to explain so I will attempt it and then edit the code but I cant get back to it for about another hour .

Comment: @SuperMegaBroBro Your approach to instantiation is a bit off. I suggest trying to grasp the basics before moving on to more advanced stuff. Unity documentation and tutorials may help you greatly. Best of luck.

Comment: yeah thanks man. i mean i used to be able to make some half decent games in unity, but Its been a long while so im just refreshing my memory more than starting from the very basics. I think i will work through some of the tutorials again though as that will surely help a lot. cheers

Comment: btw it all worked perfectly thanks. And i see that I just needed to instantiate it first. Now I can move on to making the thrusters and making the ship reappear across the screen when it leaves the screen. This should be fun haha you might see another post from me in a few hours lol